# How to wait for nested forEach statements with mongodb queries inside to return function

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, foreach

I am having a hard time figuring out the asynchronous behaviour of nested `forEach()` functions with `node.js`. I am not sure where I should create and return a promise and so on.

I have tried wrapping all the logic of the `getFeed()` function into a `return new Promise()`, but I think resolve is called before the nested `forEach()`'s are done.

```
friends = user_info.friends;

function GetFeed() {
    let post_ids = [];
    try {
        friends.forEach(async function(friend_id) {
        const posts = await db.collection('users').findOne(
              { _id: ObjectId(friend_id) },
              { projection: { posts: 1 }}
        );
        posts.posts.forEach(function(post_id) {
              console.log(post_id);
              post_ids.push(post_id);
           });
        });
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(post_ids);
        });
    } catch (err) {
         return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error, unable to collection post ids from the database.' });
    }
}

GetFeed()
  .then((post_ids) => {
        console.log(post_ids);
        return res.status(200).json({ post_ids: post_ids });
   })
```

the console.log() statements reveal that the `GetFeed().then()` executes before the `console.log()` statement in the inner `forEach` loop. I expect that the `GetFeed().then()` console.log would wait for the nest `forEach` logic to finish and then console.log the result.

Comment: See [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) which takes an *array of arguments* in a single query. Therefore just a single `find()` with `let posts = (await db.collection('users').find({ _id: { $in: friends.map(_id => ObjectId(_id)) }}).project({ posts: 1, _id: 0 }).toArray()).reduce((o,{ posts }) => [ ...o, ...posts ],[])`. Presuming of course you are *merging arrays* of `posts` in each document, and from **one** request and many results as opposed to *many* `findOne()` requests. Much better.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value **undefined**.

Meaning you cant wait for it as you can never get a promise to return from it.

You should use a `for` or `while` loop or a library like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) to iterate over an array and return promises.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a promise array an await them.

```
friends = user_info.friends;

async function GetFeed() {
    let post_ids = [];


    let postsPromiseArray = await Promise.all(
        friends.map(friend_id => {
            return db.collection('users').findOne(
                { _id: ObjectId(friend_id) },
                { projection: { posts: 1 } }
            );
        })
    )

    postsPromiseArray.forEach(posts => {
        posts.posts.forEach(function (post_id) {
            post_ids.push(post_id);
        });
    })

    return post_ids;
}

GetFeed()
    .then((post_ids) => {
        console.log(post_ids);
        return res.status(200).json({ post_ids: post_ids });
    })
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this could help you to get a desired output.

```
friends = user_info.friends;

    async function GetFeed() {
        let post_ids = [];
        try {
           await friends.forEach(async function(friend_id) {
                const posts = await db.collection('users').findOne(
                    { _id: ObjectId(friend_id) },
                    { projection: { posts: 1 }}
                );
                posts.posts.forEach(function(post_id) {
                    console.log(post_id);
                    post_ids.push(post_id);
                });
            });
            return post_ids;
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error, unable to collection post ids from the database.' });
        }
    }

    var post_ids = GetFeed()
    console.log(post_ids);
    return res.status(200).json({ post_ids });
```

Comment: `.forEach()` does not wait for callbacks and does not itself return a promise so using await inside it and after it will not do what you want.